# Rendering a variable number of text-field/input pairs with django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to render a variable number of field-name/input-box rendered using a django (v 1.3) template. In my view, I look up a table to get the column names, and then create a list of forms.CharFields() of the same size, and zip them together as follows:

```
ua_data = [forms.CharField(required=False) for i in range(len(ua_data_field_names))]
ua_fields = zip(ua_data_field_names, ua_data)
ua_field1 = forms.CharField(required=False) # temp field for testing
```

so that at the end of it, the context contains something like this (for only one field):

```
>>> ua_fields
[(u'Test field', <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x108386b50>)]
```

In my template, I'm running the following loop:

```
  {% for field in form.ua_fields %}
  <tr>
      <td>{{ field.0 }}</td>
      <td>{{ field.1 }} {{ field.1.errors }}</td>
      {#<td>{{ form.ua_field1 }} {{ form.ua_field1.errors }}</td>#}
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

That spews out the following in rendered HTML:

```
Test field  <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x1081f1c50>
```

whereas if I swap the second `<td>` above with the commented out line, I actually get an input field rendered (ua_field1 is a direct `forms.CharField` object)

What is preventing a list lookup field from doing the magic HTML rendering?

Comment: Please show how you define `ua_fields` and `ua_field1`.

Answer (score 1):

What is rendered by `{{ form.field1 }}` is not the same object as `form.fields['field1']`. It is special BoundField, which is being bound with some data and ready to render.

So you should actually populate form with `field1` ... `fieldN` on form creation, and then in `ua_fields()` zip together pairs of "'text_name', value of `self.__getitem__('fieldX')`"